# Python telnetlib read's only print "bs"

Tags: python, telnetlib

I'm trying to do some telnet automation with Python (only *pure* Python).  When I try to print some of my read's in the function `read_until`, all I see are a series of `bs`'s -- that's `bs`, as in the `backspace` character, not something else.  :-)

Does anyone know if there's some kind of setting I can change in the on `tn`, my instance of the `Telnet` class, or correct this? Or is this something that my host is spewing back? I've done some Googling on the `telnetlib` library, and I haven't seen many examples where folks have output from the `Telnet.read_until` function.

This is a cut-down version of my code:

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "blahblah"

def writeline(data):
    local.write(data + '\n')

def read_until(tn, cue, timeout=2):
    print 'Before read until "%s"' % cue
    print tn.read_until(cue, timeout)
    print 'After read until "%s"' % cue

def tn_write(tn, text, msg=''):
    if not msg:
        msg = text
    print 'Before writing "%s"' % msg
    tn.write(text)
    print 'After writing "%s"' % msg    


user = 'me'
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

read_until(tn, "Username: ")
tn_write(tn, user + "\n", user)

if password:
    read_until(tn, "Password: ")
    tn_write(tn, password + "\n", 'password')

read_until(tn, "continue")
tn_write(tn, "\n", '<Enter>')

#tn.write("vt100\n")

tn_write(tn, 'main_menu' + '\n', 'start menu')
read_until(tn, 'Selection: ')
```

I don't think it matters, but I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem here.  I tried writing my commands with both `\n` and `\r` but not both combined.  When I changed to `'\r\n'`, I got the expected output.